# Setting up an FTP server using Filezilla

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

I am trying to set up a server using filezilla but I always get this error saying

> You appear to be behind a NAT router. Please configure the passive mode settings and forward a range of ports in your router.
>   Warning: FTP over TLS is not enabled, users cannot securely log in.

I tried connecting using both the filezilla server and the filezilla client for windows. I don't have a router and I have connected my laptop to a hotspot created by my mobile phone to access the internet. Can I still set up a server if I am connected to a mobile hotspot and not a router?

Comment: Your mobile provider is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...